# Map size() Method in Java With Examples

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, size

I tried very hard to know Map size() method. But i didn't find any proper content. Please Explain the method with proper definition, syntax, parameters, Exceptions, etc.

Comment: It returns the size of the Map. You invoke like so: `yourMap.size();`.

Comment: It's documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html - please be specific about what you find unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for the Map class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), where you can find the definition of the `size()` method:

> Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map. If the map contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.

It does not have any parameters and does not throw exceptions.

In general, documentations are your friend. You can easily find information to a class that you want to know more about by googling "java <insert-name-of-class>".